# Send multiple row additions to email address

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd be grateful for your help.

At present this script sends an email to a recipient (email address contained in the spreadsheet) everytime a new row is added to my spreadsheet (using a on change trigger event). A recipient may receive multiple messages during this time.

What i'd like is for multiple rows of data to be sent in one email to a specific recipient (i'm going to change the trigger to a time driven one.)

Sample of current data:

[image]

How would you do this?

Also would I need to change the .getactive command if im doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Mark

```
function sendemail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr = 2;
  const rg = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 6);
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let Subject = "New Content on IG.com";
    let message =
      "<p><b>Title: </b>" + r[0] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Article: </b>" + r[1] + "</p>";
    let EmailSent = r[5];
    let SendTo = r[4];
    if (EmailSent != "Yes") {
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 6).setValue("Yes");
      MailApp.sendEmail({to: SendTo,cc: "",subject: Subject,htmlBody: message});
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Please do you own work

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share dummy sheets so that it will be easy for us to replicate your work. please remove sensitive data, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send one email to each recipient:

```
function sendemail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr = 2;
  const rg = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 6);
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  const sub = "New Content on IG.com";
  let eml = {pA:[]};
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let msg = "<p><b>Title: </b>" + r[0] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Article: </b>" + r[1] + "</p>";
    let sent = r[5];
    let rec = r[4];
    if (sent != "Yes") {
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 6).setValue("Yes");
      if(!eml.hasOwnProperty(r[4])) {
        eml[r[4]] = [msg]
        eml.pA.push(r[4]);
      } else {
        eml[r[4]].push(msg)
      }
    }
  });
  eml.pA.forEach(p => { MailApp.sendEmail({to: p,subject:sub,htmlBody:eml[p].join('<br>')})});
}
```